# Left arrow key is sporadically unresponsive

Tags: keyboard, hardware-failure

I use the left arrow key quite a bit in the course of my work. Over the past few days I've found that it is occasionally unresponsive, and I need to press it a second time in order to deploy it.

I'm using a Dell XPS 17 with Windows 7, which I've been using for three years with no problems until now.

Answer (score 2):

Confirming the problem:

- As Nate said, first try plugging in an external keyboard and using that for a while.  You did not say how often it occurs (once a week? once an hour?) but use the external keyboard as much as possible and see if that alleviates the problem.

You can also try and confirm via software.

- [Showoff](http://www.donationcoder.com/Software/Skrommel/index.html#ShowOff) is a piece of software that will display your keystrokes onscreen.  Unfortunately it doesn't log but if you can recreate the problem regularly then you should be able to see if it registers or not.

---

What's going on when you press a key:

*Beneath the plastic key cap is a hinge and a cup.  The cup is a flexible rubber dome with a hard carbon center. When you press a key, a plunger on the bottom of the key pushes down against the dome, and the carbon center presses against a hard, flat surface beneath the key matrix.  It presses a switch, completing the circuit and allowing a tiny amount of current to flow through.  When a circuit is closed the processor calculates which key it is and sends a message to your computer.*

If there is a crumb or something else wedged beneath the hinge it can keep the key from pressing down on the cup to make a connection with the circuit board. If this was the case you would most likely feel some resistance when pressing down and depending where the debris is pressing the key from different angles might yield different levels of consistency. To fix this you would simply remove the key cap and clean with compressed air or blowing really hard (try not to spit on the keyboard).

If there is no resistance, another possibility is that the carbon center of the cup has worn away and doesn't make proper contact to complete the circuit underneath.  In this case, replacing the cup would fix the problem. After a quick search you can pick up parts for a single key for the Dell XPS 17 from a site like [this](http://www.replacementlaptopkeys.com/dell-xps-17-l701x-laptop-key-replacement/).

Answer (score 1):

It's almost certainly your keyboard beginning to fail. Try swapping it out with another and see if that fixes the issue. If so, it's time for a new keyboard.

If you're feeling adventurous, you could open up the old one and try to see why it's making intermittent contact.